# Laravel - I am trying to delete a record from the database returns null (not working)

Tags: php, laravel

Hello fellow StackOverflow users,

I am trying to delete a record from the database using the destroy function, but it returns a null value. I think it has something to do with me using a relational model.

***Club_info.blade.php:***

```
@foreach ($speler as $s)
<tr>
  <td>{{$s->speler_naam}} 
    <a href="{!! url()->current() !!}/delete/{{$s->id}}">×</a>
 </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

***Routes file:***

```
Route::get('/view/{naam}/delete/{id}', 'VoetbalController@destroy');
```

***Controller:***

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $speler = Speler::where('id', $id)->delete();
    $speler->delete();
}
```

***Model:***

```
public function speler()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Speler', 'naam', 'club_naam');
}
```

Comment: `$speler = Speler::where('id', $id)->delete();` this snippet will already deletes the record, then no need of calling  `$speler->delete();`

Comment: As a off-topic thing, try to avoid using a GET request for an delete. It's possible browsers preload that url, possibly even on hover. Not the best thing to have records disappear without the user doing anything. For the same reason Laravel changed it's logout request to a POST.

Answer (score 5):

You are passing 2 variables `naam` and `id`.

So `$id` in your `destroy` function will automatically take value of your first parameter `{naam}`. You need to add 2 parameters in your `destroy` function in controller.

And you have called `delete()` method twise.

Change your Controller function to

```
public function destroy($naam, $id)
{
   $speler = Speler::where('id', $id)->delete();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is no magic logic in your routing, then you are missing the `$naam` variable in your destroy function.

You're deleting a delete, so the second delete is not needed.

```
public function destroy($naam, $id)
{
    Speler::where('id', '=', $id)->delete();
}
```